# Position resets to 0 while using PanGestureHandler from react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation, react-native-gesture-handler

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, Animated } from 'react-native';
import { PanGestureHandler } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';


const InfoBox = ({ info }: Props) => {
  const [currenPos, setCurrentPos] = useState<number>(0);
  const translateY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const onGestureEvent = useCallback(
    Animated.event(
      [
        {
          nativeEvent: {
            translationY: translateY,
          },
        },
      ],
      {
        useNativeDriver: true,
      },
    ),
    [],
  );

  const handleTransformStyle = {
    transform: [
      {
        translateY,
      },
      {
        translateX: -55,
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <PanGestureHandler
        onGestureEvent={onGestureEvent}
      >
        <Animated.View style={[styles.handleBar, handleTransformStyle]}>
          <View style={styles.separator} />
        </Animated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </View>
  );
};

export default InfoBox;
```

I have provided a very simple example of `PanGestureHandler`. On moving the box for the first time, it moves to a position and stays at that position. But, if I try to move it again, it starts from position zero instead of starting from the same position where I had left it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have realized this occurs due to the offset getting reset.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem.

Add `onHandlerStateChange` to `PanGestureHandler`:

```
 <PanGestureHandler
    onGestureEvent={onPanGestureEvent}
    onHandlerStateChange={onHandlerStateChange}
 >
...
</PanGestureHandler>
```

Then, create a `onHandlerStateChange` function like so:

```
  const onHandlerStateChange = useCallback(() => {
    translateY.extractOffset();
  }, []);
```

`translateY.extractOffset();` performed the magic. It sets the offset value. Phew!

Comment: Is it possible to add some sort of checks in the onGestureFunciton? Or can we only use the event directly? See this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64330969/stop-dragging-after-a-limit-has-reached

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem with PinchGestureHandler. But I try with some function such as scale.extractOffset() or scale.flattenOffset, there is no affect. Does you have any suggestion for this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation is very confusing. You might have to really implement, test and try to find a solution. That's what I had to do